# Is there a way to merge two CSV Content into one CSV using NiFi

Tags: regex, apache, csv, export-to-csv, apache-nifi

I have a main CSV called **Test1.CSV** with 1000+ fields and then I have another CSV called **Test2.CSV** with two important fields (**TestId and Uuid column**). I want to **merge the content of Test2.CSV into Test1.CSV** so that Test1.CSV have 100+ columns along with those two fields from Test2.CSv(TestId & Uuid).

What flow and configurations I should use to achieve this? Please help

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a column in Test1.CSV whose value is supposed to match a row in Test2.CSV? If so, you can bring Test1.CSV in with GetFile, ListFile -> FetchFile, etc. and then use [LookupRecord](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.7.1/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.LookupRecord/index.html) with a [CSVRecordLookupService](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-lookup-services-nar/1.7.1/org.apache.nifi.lookup.CSVRecordLookupService/index.html), where you'd point to Test2.CSV and configure it to match a field from Test1.CSV against a field in Test2.CSV. Your output schema would have to be the input schema plus the two fields you want in the output, and I believe you'd set the "Record Result Contents" to "Insert Record Fields".

Comment: No there is no common field in both CSV. Is it still possible to merge two CSV without any common field?